# sequence of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

For a sequence {f_n} of entire functions converging to f uniformly on compact subsets of C, suppose, for all n≧1, f_n has n zeroes. Then,
1. f must have infinitely many zeroes.
2. f need not have any zeroes.
3. f cannot have only finitely many   zeroes.
4. f cannot have any zero.
I know that for uniform convergence sup|f_n -f|→0 for large n, which implies that f_n and f must agree on the set of their accumulation points. Am I correct to say that option 1 is correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the sequence of partial sums of the power series for the exponential function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Rouche's Theorem on a disk $D(z_0,r)$ for some $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\bar{D}\subset $ of a compact seubset where $f_n$ converges, and $f$ has no zeros on $\partial D$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but kindly elaborate.

Comment: Answer is choice 1. Prove for sufficiently large $n$, $f$ and $f_n$ have the same number of zeros in $D$.

Comment: I have upvoted it. But dnt know where is the accept option on my phone.